# Create a Bookmarklet to Capitalize Text in a Form Field

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, capitalization

I spend quite a lot of time at work correcting capitalization errors in customer applications.  The editing page is online, and the text to be corrected is in a bunch of different text input fields.

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that would change the case of the text in the active field to Title Case (first letter every word capitalized, all other letters lowercase).

I've been trying to adapt/combine this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selection;
    $("#textarea").select(function () {
        selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    });
    $("#upper").click(function () {
        if (selection) {
            var upper = selection.toUpperCase();
            var text = $("#textarea").text();
            $("#textarea").html(text.replace(selection, upper));
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

But I'm just stuck.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what way does that not work? Can you produce a simple demo, including HTML, that shows your code in action? (Include the HTML *in the question*, and ideally add a snippet here, or link to a live (minimal) demo elsewhere, such as [JS FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)).

Comment: Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0xz9kyz/) example.  It's a mess.